# Error while testing on the android emulator

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mqtt

I receive this error while running test of my flutter MQTT code on the android emulator

```
═════ Exception caught by gesture ═════════════════════════════════════
mqtt-client::ConnectionException: The connection must be in the Connected state in order to perform this operation.
══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

dependencies:

```
flutter:
  sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  mqtt_client: ^5.5.3
```

This is the version of mqtt_client I am using

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_client.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,

      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({String title});

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState( ) => _MyHomePageState( );
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String statusLock = '';
  String topic = 'test'; //fill in the topic
  int status;
  MqttClient client = MqttClient.withPort('tailor.cloudmqtt.com', 'test', 12917); //put the mqtt info

  MqttConnectMessage connMess = MqttConnectMessage( )
      .withClientIdentifier('')
      .withWillTopic('test')
      .withWillMessage('test')
      .startClean( )
      .withWillQos(MqttQos.exactlyOnce);

  MqttClientPayloadBuilder builder = MqttClientPayloadBuilder( );

  @override
  void initState( ){
    super.initState( );
    client.onSubscribed = onSubscribed;
    client.connectionMessage = connMess;
  }

  void onSubscribed(String topic) {
    print('EXAMPLE::Subscription confirmed for topic $topic');
  }

  void contactMQTT( ) async{
    try{
      await client.connect('example1','example2'); //put mqtt id and password
    }catch (e){
      print(e);
      client.disconnect();
    }
  }

  void _unlock(int status) {
    setState(( ) {

      if (status == 0){
        statusLock = 'OPEN';
      }else {
        statusLock = 'CLOSE';
      }
    });
    builder.addInt(status.toInt( ));
    client.publishMessage(topic, MqttQos.exactlyOnce, builder.payload);
    builder.payload.clear();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Status of Lock $statusLock',
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('ON'),
                onPressed: ( ){
                  _unlock(0);
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('OFF'),
                onPressed: ( ) {
                  _unlock(1);
                },
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

can anyone help me with it?i am new to flutter. I am deploying an app that can control a lock through mqtt using the flutter & mqtt by pressing on & off button in my app.

Comment: The error implies you have tried to subscribe to a topic or publish a message before you have call the `client.connect()` method.

Comment: Sorry for that,i will edit the post. but how can i connect the topic before trying to publish a message?

Comment: You need to make sure you've called `contactMQTT()` before you try to subscribe to a topic or publish a message.

Comment: Sorry im new to flutter, is there any build in function in flutter can do that?